# Make [image-morphology] a synonym of [mathematical-morphology]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Both [mathematical-morphology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-morphology) and [image-morphology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-morphology) refer to the field of Mathematical Morphology (a sub-field of Image Processing). [image-morphology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-morphology) doesn't refer to "Mathematical Morphology" in its tiny description, but it offers a link to a web page that explains Mathematical Morphology. I guess this tag name comes about because some people refer to it as "Morphological Image Processing".

These tags have about 100 questions each, but only 16 have both. Looking through the questions, I see no difference in the usage of these two tags. All these questions refer to Mathematical Morphology.

I suggest that [image-morphology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-morphology) become a synonym of [mathematical-morphology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-morphology). I already created the [tag synonym suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mathematical-morphology/synonyms), but there are only 3 other uses that would be able to vote on it...

Comment: Can you get atleast 1 other user who's well versed in the tags to comment on this post? If one other person who's an SME in the tag agrees, then I'll approve the synonym.

Comment: I agree with this synonym

Comment: @Bhargav: Thanks! See rayryeng's support.

Comment: Thanks, approved. I'll merge after a few days.